# Using One Model inside another model in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am Developing a E-commerce Application with Django

So what I was thinking is getting the category of the Product in a separate Model and list them down in another using choice field in CharField.

So Here is the code for this

```
This is the model for getting the Categories from the user

class ProjektCat(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Option_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Option_Number = models.IntegerField()
    Number_Visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.Option_Name}'
```

and here is the code to list those categories as a dropdown in the CharField

```
class Software_And_Service(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Product_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    projectKats = ProjektCat.objects.all()
    choice = []
    for i in projectKats:
        option = (i.Option_Number, i.Option_Name)
        choice.append(option)
    Cateogary = models.CharField(
        max_length=256, choices=choice)
    Price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Description = models.TextField(default='', max_length=5000)
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.URLField(default='')
    linkToDownload = models.URLField(default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Projekt : {self.Product_Name}'
```

But it's Showing me an Error that there is no such table in *app_name*.projektcat

Is there is any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

It's not how you do this. First correctly assign the `projectKats` field i.e

```
# You can set max_length as per your choice
projectKats = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

You need to do this logic in django forms rather than django models.

So this is how you can do it.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import ProjektCat, Software_And_Service


def get_category_choices():
    return [(obj.Option_Name,obj.Option_Name) for obj in ProjektCat.objects.values_list('Option_Name',flat=True).distinct()]


class SoftwareAndServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    projectKats = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_category_choices)

    class Meta:
        model = Software_And_Service
        fields = [
                  'projectKats',
                   # whatever fields you want
                 ]
```

Comment: Hey Btw How to use forms.py in models.py??